# Чтение UDP сообщений

Tags: python, udp

Хочу прочитать на сервере  сообщения, отправленные клиентом, но ничего не выходит. При том в логах сервера получение UDP пакета отображается.

Код клиента:

```
  import socket
  UDP_IP = "46.21.252.29"
  UDP_PORT = 9090

  MESSAGE = b"Hello, World!"

  print("UDP target IP: {}".format(UDP_IP))
  print("UDP target port: {}".format(UDP_PORT))
  print("message: {}".format(MESSAGE))

  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  
  sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Код сервера:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "46.21.252.29"
UDP_PORT = 9090

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message: {}".format(data))
```

Comment: Что конкретно означает «ничего не выходит»? Если вы говорите, что в логах отображается, то это уже не «ничего», так что вопрос непонятен

Comment: @andreymal Я про то, что при запуске кода на сервере не выводится отправленное сообщение. За сервер принимается определенная виртуалка, а логи смотрелись с nat.

Comment: Код правильный. Проблема не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дошло. 
На деле ошибка была в bind (синтаксис). А второе, из-за чего я не могла поймать сообщение: неверная привязка сокета к IP. В первоначальной вариации кода бинд был на внешний IP, стоило указать локальный и "hello world" было сразу поймано.